# React Native iOS build failed due to Yoga Error

Tags: ios, react-native

I ejected from expo to pure react native project. IOS project is not running as expected. The error i got was

```
~/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.h: No such file or directory
```

More error is show below

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening TrackUs.xcodeproj

** BUILD FAILED ** The following build commands failed:
        PBXCp /Users/user/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGConfig.h /Users/user/Documents/Apps/App/ios/build/TrackUs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/yoga/YGConfig.h
        PBXCp /Users/user/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGValue.h /Users/user/Documents/Apps/App/ios/build/TrackUs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/yoga/YGValue.h
        PBXCp /Users/user/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGMarker.h /Users/user/Documents/Apps/App/ios/build/TrackUs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/yoga/YGMarker.h
        PBXCp /Users/user/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.h /Users/user/Documents/Apps/App/ios/build/TrackUs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/yoga/YGEnums.h (4 failures)
```

Is there anything I did wrong? It seem not to see the YOGA file or path.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGMarker.h: No such file or directory       Iam using react-native not expo

Comment: Try to update your pod using pod update or try ant latest react version and reinstall pod

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting the build folder `<your-project>/ios/build` and then run `react-native run-ios` again.

Comment: This worked with my error (The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure))