# Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild"

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am creating an App with my development team, by cloning the Github project and running the react-native run-ios generates the following error.

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening vamola.xcodeproj

on one topic suggested this correction;
Go to project settings in Xcode. Menu File-> Project Settings

Go to per-User Project Settings section.

Click on advanced.

Select Xcode Default option. previously this used to be Legacy for my project.

but I did not succeed.

to be able to compile my project

Comment: Are you trying to debug or create a release?

Comment: I'm trying to run the emulator to continue development

Comment: The solution works for me, try the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61923146/7885621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit)

Answer (score 4):

[React Native iOS build failed due to Yoga Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240654/react-native-ios-build-failed-due-to-yoga-error)

The only thing you need to do, is to delete the build folder in ios project

Comment: Despite this may be the answer, adding links as answers is not acceptable in SO. Consider adding the main points of the provided url in your answer.